# Refreshing Div after inserting new Data atributes

Tags: php, laravel, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to put new data attributes to my div, all is good and I can set it with jquery, but I need to reload that div in order to generate new stuff inside it. I am trying to populate new PowerBI dashboard every time user selects new dashboard. I am using powerbi.js library in order to do that, first time when page loads with strict data-attributes it works, I just thinking how to change it inside page without reloading all the page.

```
            $('#Report').attr('powerbi-access-token', apptoken);
                            $(".btn-success").click(function(){
                                 var getValue = $(this).attr('atributas');
                                 var listData = <?php echo json_encode($listas);?>;
                                 var fubar = ((listData[getValue]['name']));
                                 $('#Report').hide();
                                 $('#Report').attr('powerbi-report', listData[getValue]['id']); 
                                 $('#Report').attr('powerbi-embed', listData[getValue]['embedUrl']);   
                                 $("#Report").hide().fadeIn('fast');
                                 $('#Report').show();
                                $('#Report').reload();
                            });
                        });
                </script>

        <div class="side-body padding-top">
            <script>window.powerbi = window.powerbi || {};</script>
                 <div id="Report" powerbi-access-token="" 
                 powerbi-embed="https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed?reportId=2a647e7f-6103-4ace-a2fa-dasdasd" 
                 powerbi-report="589bacd1-aa9c-47aa-987b-asdasd" style="height:859px"> 
                </div>
```

Comment: So the idea is that the user clicks on a button with the class '.btn-success' and then - onClick - the new settings are populated and the powerbi div is refreshed? Can you add the html code with the "attributas" attribute?

Comment: that's right. Attributes changes and is alright. I just populate buttons with blade like that
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" atributas="<?php echo $i;?>">{{ $listas[$i]['name'] }}</button>` 
The problem is how to refresh that div every time I populate new stuff into that div which generates PowerBi dashboard with powerbi.js help

Comment: I think this refers to your problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/issues/4